# "Id cannot be zero" - GoogleJsonResponseException 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-endpoints

I seem to be getting an error when trying to retrieve list using endpoint in GAE. The error is as follow:

```
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650): com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650): {
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650):   "code": 400,
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650):   "errors": [
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650):     {
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650):       "domain": "global",
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650):       "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id cannot be zero",
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650):       "reason": "badRequest"
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650):     }
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650):   ],
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650):   "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id cannot be zero"
04-08 01:01:30.145: I/System.out(14650): }
```

This is the method I'm trying to use in my endpoint:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "cast", "unchecked"})
public List<Comercio> listComercio() {
   EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
   List<Comercio> result= new ArrayList<Comercio>();

   try {
      Query query = mgr.createQuery("select c from Comercio c", Comercio.class);
      for (Object obj : (List<Object>) query.getResultList()) {
        result.add((Comercio) obj);
      }
      } finally {
        mgr.close();
      }
      return result;
}
}
```

This is the entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Comercio{

@Id
private Long id;

private String title;

private String url;

private String NEWSTYPE;

public Comercio() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public void setNewstypeid(String newstypeid) {
    this.NEWSTYPE = newstypeid;
}

public String getNewstypeid() {
    return NEWSTYPE;
}

}
```

This is the AsyncTask from my android project:

```
public class AsyncDatastoreArticles extends CloudAsyncTask {

AsyncDatastoreArticles(Home activity) {
   super(activity);
}

@Override
protected void doInBackground() throws IOException {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   List<Comercio> list = endpoint.listComercio().execute().getItems();
   if (list != null) {
   //DO SOMETHING
   } 

}
}
```

Please i need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason is that ID is not being set. You can use the below code to set autogenerated id in your entity class.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
```

Also make sure to not to keep any setId() method in your entity in that case.

Answer (score 1):

It's used throughout this topic here as `Long`, but just wanted to point it out one more time:

Use Uppercase `Long`, as `long` defaults to zero..

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, there may be record in your database with Id value as 0 which will cause this error from JPA. Because as per JPA, Id should not be zero.

Please check the Database once.